# D language: initializing dynamic multidimensional array best practices?

Tags: multidimensional-array, d

Just curious if this is the best practice for initializing a dynamic, multidimensional array in [D](http://www.d-programming-language.org/index.html).  There is a section on arrays in their language reference, but I'm not quite sure if it goes over what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
class Map {
    Tile[][] tiles;

    this(uint width, uint height) {
        tiles.length = height;
        foreach (ref tilerow; tiles)
            tilerow.length = width;
    }
}

Map map1 = new Map(5000, 3000); // values determined at runtime
```

(or an equivalent alternative like a typical for (y=0;y<height;y++) loop).

My concern with this is that it reallocates each row of the array separately rather than the whole chunk all at once, so I don't know if this will lead to too much memory shuffling.  Also, I believe it's not guaranteed to be contiguous (since **tiles** is just an array of pointers in this case).  Is there any "better" way to do this (that doesn't involve using a single-dimensional array and computing the index myself)?  As far as I can tell from the docs a contiguous multidimensional array can only be declared with immutable dimensions at compile time, just wondering if I'm missing something...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can *new* the array, at least in D2:

```
Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[][](height, width);
```

I believe this is the best practice.

Comment: Well technically, _best_ practice would use `auto` on the left-hand side rather than repeating the type. But yeah, this is the best way to allocate a multi-dimensional array as long as each of them is supposed to be the same length.

Comment: Also see [http://www.d-programming-language.org/expression.html#NewExpression](http://www.d-programming-language.org/expression.html#NewExpression).

Answer (score 3):

you can fudge it by `malloc`ing every thing you need upfront

```
this(uint width, uint height) {
    void* p = enforce(GC.malloc(Tile.sizeof*width*height),new OutOfMemoryException);
          //allocate all rows at once, throw on returned null
    tiles.length = height;
    foreach (i,ref tilerow; tiles)
        tilerow = cast(Tile[])p[Tile.sizeof*width*i..Tile.sizeof*width*(i+1)];
                //slice it into the multidimensional array
}
```

**EDIT** or use a temporary array to keep hem in for cleaner/less bugprone code (i.e. hide the malloc)

```
this(uint width, uint height) {
    Tile[] p = new Tile[height*width]
    tiles.length = height;
    foreach (i,ref tilerow; tiles)
        tilerow = p[width*i..width*(i+1)];
                //slice it into the multidimensional array
}
```

Comment: Small note for the first sample: You can use enforceEx, e.g. `enforceEx!OutOfMemoryError(GC.malloc(Tile.sizeof*width*height));`, also it's not `OutOfMemoryException`, but `OutOfMemoryError`, and these require imports to `std.exception`, `core.memory` and `core.exception`.